Редактирование PDF
У нас в производстве используется программа, с помощью которой создаются управляющие программы для ЧПУ. На выходе получается 2 файла: с кодом и файл PDF (в нём изображение заготовки с инструментами и т.д., в общем, это для оператора станка).
Иногда на одной заготовке располагается несколько одинаковых деталей. Тогда PDF файлик мы печатаем, рисуем от руки разметку заготовки по деталям, сканируем это творчество и отдаём флешку с кодом и pdf оператору.
Эту разметку можно представить как табличку. Например, мы размещаем 4 одинаковых детали размером 250х50 на заготовке 1000х200. У нас получается 2 столбика и 2 строки, это 4 ячейки, каждая из которых соответствует одной детали.
Оператор выполняет программу на станке, потом заготовку рубят на 4 готовых детали.
На самом деле нарисовать и отсканировать - это дело 5 минут, но хотелось бы автоматизировать процесс. Я вижу это так:
Программа преобразует pdf в картинку, распознает заготовку, рисует на ней табличку по заданным параметрам, конвертирует обратно в pdf. Звучит логично? Или есть более простой способ? Наш софт, который генерирует эти файлы функцией визуальной разметки не обладает.

вроде бы, fpdf и reportlab умеют рисовать прямо в pdf. другое дело, что вам нужно распознать граница деталей.

возможно, вам поможет opencv, как здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57068541/detect-and-crop-a-box-in-pdf-or-image-as-individual-images

Вот тут Вам скорее всего предоставят все необходимые инструменты для работы вручную с .pdf: https://python-scripts.com/category/python-pdf
